# AngularJS Use evaluation of expression in orderBy predicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a calculated expression that amounts to a date field in one of my views, and I have a toolbar that allows for sorting.  However, I can't figure out how to sort based on the result of the date expression, not knowing how to link the predicate to the outcome of the expression:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'postDate.sec * 1000+ postDate.usec'; reverse= false">Oldest</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'postDate.sec * 1000 + postDate.usec'; reverse= true">Newest</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'children'; reverse = true">Most Comments</a></li>
  <li><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'children'; reverse = false">Least Comments</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mine first</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then in my DOM

```
//this is inside an ng-repeat="post in Posts"
<span >{{ post.postDate.sec*1000 + post.postDate.usec | date:'MMMM d, yyyy' }}</span >
```

How can my predicate evaluate the entire calculated expression?

Comment: If the predicate is a string, it is expected to be an object, such as a property name that can be used for sorting (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy). I think what you might want to do instead is to use a define a function for the predicate instead to return that expression of yours, `postDate.sec * 1000 + postDate.usec`.

Comment: well... I've also defined a function on the scope, and tried `"predicate = 'calcDate()'`,and `"predicate = calcDate()` but that didn't work either.  I have to keep `predicate` since I'm using a dynamic order by with the selection, otherwise I'd use a function within `orderBy` itself.  I've read the docs at least 10 times, but unfortunately, they're rather sparse for this filter, especially on predicate expressions

Comment: there is NO indication from the docs how a predicate declaration can be made into a function.  the predicate declaration in the docs (and your redundant fiddle) is a STRING, referencing the accessor of the node property to pass to the comparator. It's very frustrating to have the link to the docs tossed at you when you've been staring at them for 3 hours.

Comment: and besides...  I've already got the "simple use" behavior working fine, and even more sophisticated behavior not shown in the docs, however the docs only touch on the orderBy handlers, and not the predicate expressions themselves.

Comment: It was never my intention to call you out for not combing the documentation thoroughly, I apologise if you felt that way. I think I see what you are referring to now being as lacking, "... using the <, =, > operator"